# Should users know advanced and low priority features of the app?

Tags: navigation, learning, discoverability

Financial apps have lot of features, most of these features are nice-to-have features (e.g. changing PIN CODE, reports of income/outcome.. ) and advance features which few people may need (e.g. paying very specific bills, tracking selected transactions...)

Most of the users don't know that the app has this kind of features and are simply using main functions.

Should designer try to make users know that this kind of features are available? In other words does user need to know about feature he/she will never use or use very seldom?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can tell users the feature exists - in a place where showing it's available is relevant.

Changing pincode usually resides somewhere in settings, so show it's available within the settings page overview. If it's something that's rarely used - make sure you adhere to that hierarchy and don't place it at the top. This way you're not hiding its existence, nor taking away space for features that are used more often.

Users that are looking for an obscure feature will imagine under which main topic they could logically find this, and then go look for it. If your application structure is sound, they will find it intuitively. If you have a menu item called dashboard, or transactions, they will go look there for a reporting feature.

If your users are mainly using what you already push as main features - then it sounds like your application is doing what it should be doing. If they're complaining why you haven't added certain features yet, when it is in fact available, then you should look at changing the hierarchy and visibility of features. Then it is clear that your layout structure is making things hard to find.

Actions/features that are used a lot should be easy to see and navigate to, things that are used sparingly or are considered advanced can be placed deeper within the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Much has been said about the topic of predictability and discover ability. When we try solving a discover ability problem - which should understand, is it making something the user knows exist or things should be there available (Predictability), or is it about making the user aware of a feature, they are not aware exists.

In you questions you are asking about features - which the users are not aware that exists. A good way might be making it find-able by putting it under the correct category, making it discoverable by making users aware that this or features exists, by prominently displaying a way to get there. Like settings button which is extremely obvious.